# Can't use #available to check iOS version with ViewBuilder

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm creating a SwiftUI app that is using mostly iOS 13 code, with a bit of iOS 14 code. I'm trying to use `if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {}` in the body of my views when I use iOS 14 code. When I try, I get the following error.

> Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with function builder 'ViewBuilder'

Why am I getting this error, and what can I do to solve it?

Comment: Could you post your code? It's hard to say if this is Xcode version related, because it may be SwiftUI related instead. Code would be helpful to actually duplicate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Xcode are you using?  I have similar code in a project with target set to iOS 13.0 and I do not get the message.  I have something like this and it works.

```
var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            os_log("running iOS 14.0")
        }
       VStack {
        Text("iOS 13.0")
       }
}
```